# Proof of higher order inverse of a matrix using SVD

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the SVD of a matrix $A$, $A =USV^T$ we may compute $A^{-1}$ by $A^{-1} = VS^{-1}U^{T}$ (which I think is Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse, correct on this please). This is because $V^{T}= V^{-1}$ and $U^{T} = U^{-1}$.

Similarly, using SVD we may compute $A^{-1/2}$ which according to text is $A^{-1/2} = VS^{-1/2}U^{T}$. I have tryied to prove the later furmula but I concluded with $A^{-1/2} = (USV^T)^{-1/2} = (V^T)^{-1/2}S^{-1/2}U^{-1/2}$ different with the previous equation.

Clould you please give a hint on how can we prove $A^{-1/2} = VS^{-1/2}U^{T}$?

Thanks!

Comment: note thet Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse is sth else, it is a left or right inverse of the product of a singular matrix with its transpose. The question, as is, refers to the actual inverse of a full-tank matrix via SVD

Comment: @5xum I made some changes. I hope that helps.

Comment: $X^{-\frac12}$ is only defined for positive definite matrices, because $X^\frac12$ is only defined for such matrices. Therefore, $U^{-\frac12}$ doesn't make sense in general.

Comment: What is your definition of $A^{-1/2}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $S$ is the matrix of the singular values, say
$$
S=\begin{bmatrix}
s_1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & s_2 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & s_k & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $s_1\ge s_2\ge\dots \ge s_k>0$, then the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $S$ is $S^+$, where
$$
(S^+)^T=\begin{bmatrix}
s_1^{-1} & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & s_2^{-1} & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & s_k^{-1} & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, if we consider $B=VS^+U^T$, we have
$$
ABA=USV^TVS^+U^TUSV^T=USS^+SV^T=USV^T=A
$$
and the other properties of the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse are checked similarly. So
$$
VS^+U^T
$$
is indeed the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $A$. Note that it's not necessary that $A$ be a square matrix.

For the square root, one generally assumes that $A$ is symmetric (and positive semidefinite); in this case the SVD decomposition assumes the simpler form $A=USU^T$, so you can define $S^{1/2}$ as the diagonal matrix having the square roots of $S$ along the diagonal and
$$
(US^{1/2}U^T)^2=US^{1/2}U^TUS^{1/2}U^T=USU^T=A
$$
so you can consider $A^{1/2}=US^{1/2}U^T$.

Comment: Does the matrix $A$ should be positive definite (includes symmetry and non-singularity)?

Comment: @Thoth For the square root it's not necessary that it is positive definite (only semidefinite); however, only in the positive definite case there's uniqueness, AFAIR.

Comment: Something last, given the fact that Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse is computed in rectangular matrices, can we compute $A^{-1/2}$ for rectangular matrix too? Could you please enlighten on that? Thanks again!!

Comment: @Thoth What should it mean? You can't do $A^2$ if $A$ is not square.

Comment: Thans again egreg for your help!